# MimeKit MimeMessage.CreateFromMailMessage method not found

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, mimekit

I am trying to use MimeKit 2.0.3 in a .NET Core 2.0 library.  The MimeMessage.CreateFromMailMessage method is not found.  I can see just a few other methods like Load and LoadAsync, but that is all.

I also have a .NET Framework 4.7.1 console program that tests MimeKit...the CreateFromMailMessage method is found there just fine (not a .NET Core console).

Sample code code:

```
MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
...
MimeKit.MimeMessage mimeMessage = MimeKit.MimeMessage.CreateFromMailMessage(email);
```

Answer (score 0):

The MimeKit nuget package includes support for .NET Standard 1.6 and .NET Standard 2.0.  This means that it does not/can't support .NET Core 2.0 since the System.Net.Mail namespace didn't exist in .NET Standard 2.0.

There is a pre-processor directive in MimeMessage (ENABLE_SNM) that only builds the CreateFromEmailMessage if this directive is defined...which is is not for the MimeKit.NetStandard project.  Hence no support for .NET Core 2.0 even though it includes the new System.Net.Mail namespace.

I was able to fix by adding the ENABLE_SNM directive to the MimeKit.NetStandard (project properties Build), then modified the MimeKit.NetStandard project file:

Before

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.3;netstandard1.6;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

After

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

This allowed me to just rebuild the MimeKit.NetStandard and use that single result .dll file in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with MimeKit 4.0 and .Net Core 2.1, it seems MimeKit 4.0 works with .Net Framework 4.6.2 but not .Net Core 2.1.

I found MimeKit 3.2 works with .Net Core 2.1.